# Assistance clicking this thing [NOT SURE IF BUTTON]in a vb.net webbrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, button, browser

Ok, I have tried so many times to get this right, but have always failed...can someone help me click this button? The code is...

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_306925();">
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<div class="btn3">Like</div>
</a>
```

Thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean "click this button?"

Comment: automattically click, like to click the google sign up button, you would use this- 
Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submitbutton").InvokeMember("click")

Comment: Okay so why don't you use that?

Comment: doesn't work, as you can see above, no id, and there is an "onclick", not sure what that is.

Comment: Use `GetElementsByClassName`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the element, and then invoke the correct member, for example:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "single_like_button btn3-wrap" Then
        elem.InvokeMember("onclick")
    End If
Next
```

Try changing `"class"` to `"classname"` as sometimes the second one is needed.